# Singular or Plural for between 2 matches?

Tags: grammatical-number

The boxing match between "Ryo Akaho and Toyoto Shiraishi" and "Andrew Murray and Erick Plumeri" has yet to start?

or

The boxing matches between "Ryo Akaho and Toyoto Shiraishi" and "Andrew Murray and Erick Plumeri" have yet to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example is the correct form.

The first one makes it sound as if there are going to be four boxers in the ring at the same time, two teams of two. How interesting! I wonder if anyone has ever thought of *doubles* as in tennis, applied to boxing?

Comment: @Jesse Elliot Thanks for your edit. It is rather better that way around.

Comment: Tag boxing perhaps?